# Converting string lists from a text file to int arrays

Tags: python

```
{'00': ['000011110000111111110000',
        '000011110000111111110000',
        '000011110000111111110000',
        '000010000000111000000000',
        '111110000111111000000111',
        '111110000111111000000111',
        '111110000111111000000111',
        '111001111111111000000111',
        '000001110000000000000111',
        '000011110000000011111111',
        '000011110000000011111111',
        '000011110000000011111111',
        '111111110000000011110000',
        '111111110000000011110000',
        '111111110000000011110000',
        '111000000000000010000000',
        '111000000111111110000111',
        '111000000111111110000111',
        '111000000111111110000111',
        '111000000111111001111111',
        '000000000111000001110000',
        '000011111111000011110000',
        '000011111111000011110000',
        '000011111111000011110000'],
 '01': ['01111111000000',
        '01111111000000',
        '01111111000000',
        '01110000000000',
        '01110000000000',
        '01110000000000',
        '11110000000111',
        '11110000000111',
        '11110000000111',
        '00000000000111',
        '00000111111111'],
 '02': ['0000111100',
        '0000111000',
        '1111111001',
        '0000000111',
        '0000000111',
        '0000000111',
        '0010000100',
        '0001000100',
        '0000000100',
        '0000000100']}
```

I have a text file that looks like that. I want the output file to just extract the values from the dictionary and write them to another array.Also it should be in the same order as they appear now. So the array of 00 should appear first followed by 01,02,and so on.
Output for 00-

```
['000011110000111111110000','000011110000111111110000','000011110000111111110000','000010000000111000000000','111110000111111000000111','111110000111111000000111','111110000111111000000111','111001111111111000000111','000001110000000000000111','000011110000000011111111','000011110000000011111111','000011110000000011111111','111111110000000011110000','111111110000000011110000','111111110000000011110000','111000000000000010000000','111000000111111110000111','111000000111111110000111','111000000111111110000111','111000000111111001111111','000000000111000001110000']
```

Output for 01-

```
['01111111000000','01111111000000','01111111000000','01110000000000', '01110000000000','01110000000000','11110000000111','11110000000111','11110000000111', '00000000000111','00000111111111']
```

I tried using json to solve this problem but apparently each element is a list and it doesnt work.

Comment: You realize that dictionaries are not in all Python versions ordered? So that the keys can be ordered in any possible order?

Comment: I just want all the lists of keys to be ordered in the the order of their keyys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised Python's `json` module did not work for you, so I stored your input in a file called `sample.json` and tried it myself.

The problem is that your json is not formatted the way Python expects it to be. It uses single quotes(`'`) instead of double quotes(`"`) for delimiting strings. After opening your file in my text editor and replacing all the single quotes with double quotes, Python3's `json` module worked just fine for me. Here is my Python shell session:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('./sample.json', 'r') as jfile:
        j = json.load(jfile)

>>> j['02'] 
['0000111100', '0000111000', '1111111001', '0000000111', 00000111',
'0000000111', '0010000100', '0001000100', '0000000100', 000000100']
```

Now I could open the output file (`output.json`) and write my list to it.

```
>>> with open('./output.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(str(j['01'])) # Remember to convert the list to a string!
198
```

And after exiting the python shell, the list was right where it belongs:

```
$ cat output.json
['01111111000000', '01111111000000', '01111111000000', '01110000000000', 
'01110000000000', '01110000000000', '11110000000111', '11110000000111', 
'11110000000111', '00000000000111', '00000111111111']
```

Maybe you want to give the `json` module another chance now? Granted, it's a bit picky about its input. But once you've satisfied it, it will make your work with your data much clearer, simpler, and less error-prone than slicing and dicing everything by hand.